# Referencing external text data file in JNLP configuration

Tags: jnlp

I'm trying to figure out how to include a reference to a external data file (in text form) that I want distributed along with my application via Web Start (JNLP). Sifting through the documentation for the JNLP structure, I see that you can include references to JAR, nativelib, and extensions - however, I don't see a means to include a text file resource. How can I accomplish this so that Web Start will download the text file from the server and store it locally along with my application?

Thanks!

Comment: You could hardcode a default version (like an ini file) and create it first time.

Answer (score 0):

I would store it in the app's JAR and load it as resource stream via class loader.